# How to SOQL more than one object in a batch class

Tags: apex, soql, batch

How to query more than one object in a batch class? Is it possible please let me a example code for it.

Comment: are they related objects ?

Answer (score 2):

Use SOSL for this as SOSL returns a List which implements the iterable interface. Define your Batch apex to return an Iterable instead of a QueryLocator

```
public Iterable<Object> start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return (Iterable<Object>)[[FIND 'map*' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Account (Id, Name), Contact, Opportunity, Lead])];
    }
```